# Capture input value and display the value on button click with angular material input

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material

I am working on Angular and had a simple code as shown below. How do I capture the input value when the "set" button is clicked and display on `displayText` through string interpolation?

```
<div>
    <h3>You just entered: <span>{{displayText}}</span></h3>
</div>
<div>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Insert your text">
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div>
    <button mat-button>Set</button>
</div>
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a template variable on your input field: `#input`

And handle the click event on the button:

```
(click)="displayText = input.value"
```

Give this a try:

```
<div>
    <h3>You just entered: <span>{{displayText}}</span></h3>
</div>
<div>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Insert your text" #input>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div>
  <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="displayText = input.value">Set</button>
</div>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hfhwk4?file=app/form-field-appearance-example.html) for your ref.